# Console won't print out the info from my method

Tags: c#, console

When I try to output the method call I get a blank screen, when I hit any key I get the namespace displayed then the console shuts down. Anyone see what I am missing here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace programming_2
{
class Driver 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        fraction frac = new fraction(); // we'll get 0/1
        frac = new fraction(1, 5);       // we'll get 1/5
       // frac = new fraction(25);        // we'll get 25/1
        //frac = new fraction(9.25);      // we'll get 37/4
        //frac = new fraction("6.25");    // we'll get 25/4

        //frac = new fraction(System.Console.ReadLine());


        Console.Write(frac);
        // displays the current value of frac object;

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue..");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

Fraction Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace programming_assignment_2
{
 class fraction :  ICloneable, IEnumerable<fraction>, IEnumerator<fraction>, IComparer<fraction>
{

        private int num, den;

        // Constructors

        public fraction()
        {
            Initialize(0, 1);
        }

        public fraction(int num)
        {
            CheckMinValue(num);
            Initialize(num, 1);
        }

        public fraction(fraction f)
        {
            Initialize(f.num, f.den);
        }

        public fraction(int num, int den)
        {
            CheckDenominatorZero(den);

            CheckMinValue(num);
            CheckMinValue(den);

            fraction f = new fraction((decimal)num, (decimal)den);
            Initialize(f.num, f.den);
        }

        private static void CheckMinValue(int n)
        {
            if (n == int.MinValue)
                throw new OverflowException();
        }

        private void Initialize(int num, int den)
        {
            this.num = num;
            this.den = den;
        }

        private fraction(decimal r1, decimal r2)
        {
            decimal gcd = GCD(Math.Abs(r1), Math.Abs(r2));

            int num = (int)(r1 / gcd);
            int den = (int)(r2 / gcd);

            CheckMinValue(num);
            CheckMinValue(den);

            if (r2 < 0)
            {
                num = -num;
                den = -den;
            }

            this.num = num;
            this.den = den;
        }



        public int Numerator
        {
            get { return this.num; }
        }

        public int Denominator
        {
            get { return this.den; }
        }

        // Overloaded  Operators ( +-*/^ )

        // Add

        public static fraction operator +(fraction a, fraction b)
        {
            decimal d1 = (decimal)a.num * b.den + (decimal)b.num * a.den;
            decimal d2 = (decimal)a.den * b.den;
            return new fraction(d1, d2);
        }

        public static fraction operator +(fraction a, int b)
        {
            return a + new fraction(b);
        }

        public static fraction operator +(int a, fraction b)
        {
            return new fraction(a) + b;
        }


       // Substract

        public static fraction operator -(fraction a, fraction b)
        {
            decimal r1 = (decimal)a.num * b.den - (decimal)b.num * a.den;
            decimal r2 = (decimal)a.den * b.den;
            return new fraction(r1, r2);
        }

        public static fraction operator -(fraction a, int b)
        {
            return a - new fraction(b);
        }

        public static fraction operator -(int a, fraction b)
        {
            return new fraction(a) - b;
        }


        // Multiply

        public static fraction operator *(fraction a, fraction b)
        {
            decimal r1 = (decimal)a.num * b.num;
            decimal r2 = (decimal)a.den * b.den;
            return new fraction(r1, r2);
        }

        public static fraction operator *(fraction a, int b)
        {
            return a * new fraction(b);
        }

        public static fraction operator *(int a, fraction b)
        {
            return new fraction(a) * b;
        }



        // Divide

        public static fraction operator /(fraction a, fraction b)
        {
            decimal r1 = (decimal)a.num * b.den;
            decimal r2 = (decimal)a.den * b.num;

            if (r2 == 0)
                throw new DivideByZeroException();
            else
                return new fraction(r1, r2);
        }

        public static fraction operator /(fraction a, int b)
        {
            return a / new fraction(b);
        }

        public static fraction operator /(int a, fraction b)
        {
            return new fraction(a) / b;
        }


        // Exponents

        public static fraction operator ^(fraction a, int n)
        {
            return new fraction((decimal)Math.Pow(a.num, n), (decimal)Math.Pow(a.den, n));
        }



        // Comparison operators

        public static bool operator ==(fraction a, fraction b)
        {
            return (decimal)a.num * b.den == (decimal)b.num * a.den;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(fraction a, fraction b)
        {
            return (!(a == b));
        }

        public static bool operator >(fraction a, fraction b)
        {
            return (decimal)a.num * b.den > (decimal)b.num * a.den;
        }

        public static bool operator >=(fraction a, fraction b)
        {
            return (!(a < b));
        }

        public static bool operator <(fraction a, fraction b)
        {
            return (decimal)a.num * b.den < (decimal)b.num * a.den;
        }

        public static bool operator <=(fraction a, fraction b)
        {
            return (!(a > b));
        }




        public static decimal GCD(decimal a, decimal b)
        {
            if (b == 0)
                return a;
            return GCD(b, a % b);
        }

        private static void CheckDenominatorZero(decimal den)
        {
            if (den == 0)
                throw new ArithmeticException("The denominator can't be zero!!");
        }



    }




}
```

Comment: You are not calling any method of `frac` object. Better show us definition of `fraction` class.

Comment: @steveneck - I may be blind... but I do not see where you override ToString anywhere....

Comment: But there are some other issues in the constructor. Why you need another instance of the class in the constructor and after initialize nothing is going to happen?

Comment: I just copied/pasted your code and it works fine for me (after overriding ToString()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the fraction class? Does it have a ToString() method in it that would print that out?

This works for me.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var frac = new fraction(1,5); 

            Console.WriteLine(frac);
           Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue..");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }



public class fraction
    {
        public int nom { get; set; }
        public int denom { get; set; }
        public fraction(int n, int d)
        {
            nom = n;
            denom = d;

        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0}\\{1}", nom, denom);
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, there is one for that too. All my methods and everything appear to be in order, I just started with C# a couple weeks ago and I can't seem to get any info displayed on the console

Comment: @steveneck could you paste in the code for the fraction class?

Answer (score 0):

In your code it looks like you have an endless loop:

```
public fraction(int num, int den)
{
    CheckDenominatorZero(den);

    CheckMinValue(num);
    CheckMinValue(den);

    // You are creating a new instance in the creation of a new instance
    fraction f = new fraction((decimal)num, (decimal)den);
    Initialize(f.num, f.den);
}
```

Try this:

```
    // Remove this line:
    fraction f = new fraction((decimal)num, (decimal)den);
    // And change the next line to this:
    Initialize(num, den);
```

After change:

```
public fraction(int num, int den)
{
    CheckDenominatorZero(den);

    CheckMinValue(num);
    CheckMinValue(den);

    Initialize(num, den);
}
```

Also, as others have said, you should override ToString so your console output looks nice:

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}\\{1}", this.num, this.den);
    }
```

Comment: @GrantWinney ah, good point. I guess that's not the problem, but it still is a big overhead. :p